# XMPP implementation of XEP-0198 in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire

Note: Server has already stream management installed and working.

Here is my code:

```
XMPPStreamManagementMemoryStorage *storage1=[[XMPPStreamManagementMemoryStorage alloc] init];
xmppStreamManagement=[[XMPPStreamManagement alloc] initWithStorage:storage1];
xmppStreamManagement.autoResume = YES;
[xmppStreamManagement enableStreamManagementWithResumption:TRUE maxTimeout:5];
[xmppStreamManagement addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppStreamManagement activate:xmppStream];
 [xmppStreamManagement requestAck];
```

I also implemented it delegate method as well.
But Neither i am getting response in delegate method nor look stream management working.

How will it work and how can we verify it?

Here,if I got success implementation of stream management on iOS side,then would lost offline message automatically come to

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to enable `XMPPStreamManagement` in your iOS app.

Initialise your `XMPPStreamManagement` instance with `XMPPStreamManagementMemoryStorage`.

```
XMPPStreamManagementMemoryStorage *xmppSMMS = [[XMPPStreamManagementMemoryStorage alloc] init];
xmppStreamManagement = [[XMPPStreamManagement alloc] initWithStorage:xmppSMMS];
```

Add your implementation class as its delegate

```
[xmppStreamManagement addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Now enable the stream management once the `XMPPStream` is connected and bindings have taken place.

```
[xmppStreamManagement activate:xmppStream];
xmppStreamManagement.autoResume = YES;
[xmppStreamManagement enableStreamManagementWithResumption:YES maxTimeout:0];
[xmppStreamManagement requestAck];
```

Implement the delegate methods

```
- (void)xmppStreamManagement:(XMPPStreamManagement *)sender wasEnabled:(NSXMLElement *)enabled{
}

- (void)xmppStreamManagement:(XMPPStreamManagement *)sender wasNotEnabled:(NSXMLElement *)failed{
}

- (void)xmppStreamManagement:(XMPPStreamManagement *)sender didReceiveAckForStanzaIds:(NSArray *)stanzaIds{
}
```

Comment: Hello Friend, in my case delegate does not call. can you please help me our ?

Answer (score 1):

Call the stream management after authentication is successful.

Also do not forget to call **'sendAck()'** method.

```
// Stream Management
let xmppSMMS = XMPPStreamManagementMemoryStorage()
xmppStreamManagement = XMPPStreamManagement(storage: xmppSMMS, dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
xmppStreamManagement.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
xmppStreamManagement.activate(xmppStream)
xmppStreamManagement.autoResume = true
xmppStreamManagement.ackResponseDelay = 0.2
xmppStreamManagement.requestAck()
xmppStreamManagement.automaticallyRequestAcks(afterStanzaCount: 1, orTimeout: 10)
xmppStreamManagement.automaticallySendAcks(afterStanzaCount: 1, orTimeout: 10)
xmppStreamManagement.enable(withResumption: true, maxTimeout: 0)
xmppStreamManagement.sendAck()
xmppStream.register(xmppStreamManagement)
```

Please check below link. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51018129/2781720